# Simple JavaScript & jQuery Functions 'Sometimes' Run Too Many Times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've built a demo that simply allows you to create new rows and delete them. The rows are given a unique `data-id` attribute and an object where each data-id is pushed into a `rows` array.

For some reason, clicking the remove row icon sometimes tries to delete it numerous times - for example, do the following:

Open the JS console, add 2 extra rows (by clicking 'Add one row' twice) then delete the middle row number 2 (by clicking the remove icon on the left of the row) and you'll see that the console logs 'Removed Row 2' twice - it should only log it once. If you create numerous rows and then remove rows, it sometimes repeats the action multiple times.

Does anyone know why this happens, and how to fix? I'm stumped. It should only happen once, and I assume that the entire function is running numerous times. Any fix and 'best practices' advice would be very helpful, thanks.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/drWyQb

```js
let templateRow, addBtn, templateRows, tableBody, popup, objects, rows = [];

$(document).ready(function(){
    runDefaults();
});

function runDefaults() {
    $(".no_entries_row").detach().insertBefore(".template_row");
    $('.template_row').first().attr('data-id', '1');
    defineVariables();
    removeRow();
    testEmpty();
    showSuccess();
    addRow();
    changeBg();
}

function defineVariables() {
    templateRow = $('<div>').append($('.template_row').clone()).html();
    addBtn = $('.list_add');
    templateRows = $('.template_row');
    popup = $(".popup");
    tableBody = $('tbody');
}

function removeRow() {
    let removeId;
    
    // REPEATING ERROR SOMEWHERE HERE?
    templateRows.on("click", ".controls", function(){
        removeId = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');
        $(this).parent().fadeOut(0, function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
        templateRows = $('.template_row');
        testEmpty();
        rows = rows.filter(obj => obj.id != removeId); console.log('Removed Row ' + removeId);
    });
}

function testEmpty() {
    let rowsLen = $('.template_row').length,
        noEntriesRow = $('.no_entries_row');
    if (rowsLen === 0)
        noEntriesRow.css('display','table-row');
    else
        noEntriesRow.css('display','none');
}
    
function showSuccess() {
    $(".submit").click(function(){
        popup.fadeIn();
    });
}

function addRow() {
    let id = 1;
    new rowObj(1);
    
    addBtn.on("click", function(){        
        id++;
        tableBody.append(templateRow);
        templateRows = $('.template_row');
        noOfRows = templateRows.length;
        $('.template_row:nth-of-type(' + (noOfRows+1) + ')').attr('data-id', id);
        removeRow();
        testEmpty();
        changeBg();
        new rowObj(id);
    });
}

function changeBg() {
    $(".label").change(function () {
    let colour = this.value;
        $(this).parent().parent().css('background', colour);
    });
}

function rowObj(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = 'Table Row';
    
    rows.push(this);
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    padding: 30px;
    font-family: arial;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
tbody tr:not(:last-of-type), thead tr { border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc }
thead th {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    padding: 10px;
}
td { padding: 10px 10px 10px 0 }
.no_entries_row > td { padding-left: 60px }
.btn_col, .controls { text-align: center }
.controls { padding: 0 }
a.list_cancel { color: #000 }
a.list_add {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #54A2CE;
}
i[class*="fa fa-plus-square"] { color: #999999 }
.action_btn {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: center;
    width: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.action_btn input { margin: 0 }
input[name~="submit"] {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.popup {
    flex: 1 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    display: none;
}
.popup > p {
    padding: 20px 50px;
    background: lightgreen;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
@media (min-width: 950px) {
   .popup > p {
       width: 25%;
       margin: 0 auto;
    } 
}
input, select {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
select {
    -webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
    -moz-appearance: menulist-button;
    appearance: menulist-button;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Demo</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>     
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
 
            <table class="common_table" cellspacing="0">
          
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="btn_col"></th>
             <th class="code_col">Demo Column 1</th>
             <th>Demo Column 2</th>
             <th class="data_col">Demo Column 3</th>
             <th class="data_col">Demo Column 4</th>
             <th class="short_col">Col 5</th>
             <th class="data_col">Demo Column 6</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            
            <tr class="template_row">
             <td class="controls"><a href="#" class="list_cancel" title="Delete Row"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></a></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="" id="productcode" name="" value=""/></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="long" id="productname" name="" value=""/></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="" id="stock" name="" value=""/></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="" id="vendor" name="" value=""/></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="" id="" class="label">
                        <option value = ""></option>
                        <option value = "green" style="background-color:green;">Success</option>
                        <option value = "red" style="background-color:red;">Wrong</option>
                        <option value = "orange" style="background-color:orange;">Error</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" class="" id="client" name="" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
   <tr class="no_entries_row">
             <td colspan="7">No Entries</td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
            </table>
            
         <a href="#" class="list_add"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Add one row</a>
            
            <br class="clear" />
            
            <div class="action_btn">
                <input name="submit" class="action_btn submit" type="submit" value="Save"/>
                <input name="submit" class="action_btn cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel"/>
                <div class="popup">
                    <p>Saved successfully!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
             
        </div>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I haven't been through this in great detail, but the problem is that whenever you add a new row, you add a new event listener to the add button - and one of the things this does is call `removeRow`. It seems that `removeRow` in turn sets up the event listener for the button to remove that row. So in total that event listener is in effect being created once for each time the add button is clicked - which is why after clicking it twice, the function runs twice when deleting a row. (I also tried adding 5 rows, and indeed the console.log happened 5 times.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is, in my humble opinion, ***way too complex***.

Below is the same row add/remove behavior *without your actual issue* and the row coloring based on the `<select>` change... With only 3 event handlers.

I did not touch your HTML markup. I added one single CSS rule (to hide the template row)... And completely re-writen the code from scratch.

Feel super-free for questions, since there potentially is many things to explain. ;)

The key, I think, is that I focussed on **events** triggered by a user more than on *"sub-functions naming"*. The result is 28 lines versus 84...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var table_body = $(".common_table tbody");
  
  // "Add one row" link
  $(".list_add").on("click",function(){
    console.log("Added a row");
    $(".no_entries_row").hide();
    var clone = $(".template_row").clone().removeClass("template_row");
    table_body.append(clone);
  });
  
  // Remove row icon
  $(document).on("click",".list_cancel",function(){
    console.log("Removed a row");
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    if(table_body.find("tr:visible").length==0){
      console.log("No more row!");
      $(".no_entries_row").show();
    }
  });
  
  // Select "success/wrong/error"
  $(document).on("change",".label",function(){
    console.log("Changed color");
    $(this).closest("tr").css({"background-color":$(this).val()});
  });
});  // End ready
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    padding: 30px;
    font-family: arial;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
tbody tr:not(:last-of-type), thead tr { border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc }
thead th {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    padding: 10px;
}
td { padding: 10px 10px 10px 0 }
.no_entries_row > td { padding-left: 60px }
.btn_col, .controls { text-align: center }
.controls { padding: 0 }
a.list_cancel { color: #000 }
a.list_add {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #54A2CE;
}
i[class*="fa fa-plus-square"] { color: #999999 }
.action_btn {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: center;
    width: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.action_btn input { margin: 0 }
input[name~="submit"] {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.popup {
    flex: 1 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    display: none;
}
.popup > p {
    padding: 20px 50px;
    background: lightgreen;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
@media (min-width: 950px) {
   .popup > p {
       width: 25%;
       margin: 0 auto;
    } 
}
input, select {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
select {
    -webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
    -moz-appearance: menulist-button;
    appearance: menulist-button;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 25px;
}

/* ============ ADDED =========== */
.template_row{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">

  <table class="common_table" cellspacing="0">

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="btn_col"></th>
        <th class="code_col">Demo Column 1</th>
        <th>Demo Column 2</th>
        <th class="data_col">Demo Column 3</th>
        <th class="data_col">Demo Column 4</th>
        <th class="short_col">Col 5</th>
        <th class="data_col">Demo Column 6</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <tr class="template_row">
        <td class="controls"><a href="#" class="list_cancel" title="Delete Row"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></a></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="" id="productcode" name="" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="long" id="productname" name="" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="" id="stock" name="" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="" id="vendor" name="" value="" /></td>
        <td>
          <select name="" id="" class="label">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="green" style="background-color:green;">Success</option>
            <option value="red" style="background-color:red;">Wrong</option>
            <option value="orange" style="background-color:orange;">Error</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" class="" id="client" name="" value="" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="no_entries_row">
        <td colspan="7">No Entries</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>

  <a href="#" class="list_add"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Add one row</a>

  <br class="clear" />

  <div class="action_btn">
    <input name="submit" class="action_btn submit" type="submit" value="Save" />
    <input name="submit" class="action_btn cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" />
    <div class="popup">
      <p>Saved successfully!</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/oVWgMY?editors=1111)

Comment: brilliant, thank you! I like the way you coded that. You didn't add the id or objects, but I added these after using the code you initially rebuilt: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pYPdjN

Comment: Ok about the objects... I didn't know the usage, so I skipped it. About all the input ids, It should be replaced by classes, if you intend to use a specific selector... Since it is a cloned row. ;) Happy coding!